# InfluxDB average of distinct count over time

Tags: influxdb

Using Influx DB v0.9, say I have this simple query:

```
select count(distinct("id")) FROM "main" WHERE time > now() - 30m and time < now() GROUP BY time(1m)
```

Which gives results like:

```
08:00 5
08:01 10
08:02 5
08:03 10
08:04 5
```

Now I want a query that produces points with an average of those values over 5 minutes.  So the points are now 5 minutes apart, instead of 1 minute, but are an average of the 1 minute values.  So the above 5 points would be 1 point with a value of the result of (5+10+5+10+5)/5.

This does not produce the results I am after, for clarity, since this is just a count, and I'm after the average.

```
select count(distinct("id")) FROM "main" WHERE time > now() - 30m and time < now() GROUP BY time(5m)
```

This doesn't work (gives errors):

```
select mean(distinct("id")) FROM "main" WHERE time > now() - 30m and time < now() GROUP BY time(5m)
```

Also doesn't work (gives error):

```
select mean(count(distinct("id"))) FROM "main" WHERE time > now() - 30m and time < now() GROUP BY time(5m)
```

In my actual usage "id" is a string (content, not a tag, because count distinct not supported for tags in my version of InfluxDB).

Answer (score 5):

To clarify a few points for readers, in InfluxQL, functions like `COUNT()` and `DISTINCT()` can only accept fields, not tags. In addition, while `COUNT()` supports the nesting of the `DISTINCT()` function, most nested or sub-functions are not yet supported. In addition, nested queries, subqueries, or stored procedures are not supported.

However, there is a way to address your need using continuous queries, which are a way to automate the processing of data and writing those results back to the database.

First take your original query and make it a [continuous query](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/latest/query_language/continuous_queries/) (CQ).

`CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY count_foo ON my_database_name BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT("id")) AS "1m_count" INTO main_1m_count FROM "main" GROUP BY time(1m)
END`

There are other options for the CQ, but that basic one will wake up every minute, calculate the `COUNT(DISTINCT("id"))` for the prior minute, and then store that result in a new measurement, `main_1m_count`.

Now, you can easily calculate your 5 minute mean COUNT from the pre-calculated 1 minute COUNT results in `main_1m_count`:

`SELECT MEAN("1m_count") FROM main_1m_count WHERE time > now() - 30m GROUP BY time(5m)`

(Note that [by default](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/latest/troubleshooting/frequently_encountered_issues/#querying-after-now), InfluxDB uses `epoch 0` and `now()` as the lower and upper time range boundaries, so it is redundant to include `and time < now()` in the `WHERE` clause.)